# trying to use wc(word count) inside of a script to count the words, chars, lines of a file

Tags: shell-script, files, wc

i am trying to write a shell script for my OS course. but i can not get it to read the contents of a file. only seems to read what i enter in response to the question. not sure what i am missing (watch it be super simple). thank you ahead of time.

```
echo "what file do you want to count? "
read file
mystring=$file
for token in $mystring;
do
    echo -n "lines: ";
    echo -n $token | wc -l;
    echo -n "words: ";
    echo -n $token | wc -w;
    echo -n "chars: ";
    echo -n $token | wc -c;
done
```

Comment: change mystring=$file to mystring=$(cat ${file})

Comment: That will split the contents of the file into whitespace delimited words - and then try to count the lines etc. in each word. Really what is wanted here is just `wc -l < "$file"`, `wc -w < "$file"`, `wc -c < "$file"`, no?

Comment: Thank you both for the help. it put me on the right path.

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The script that you wrote will count the lines etc. in the string entered by the user, not in the file corresponding to that filename.

This is a script that does what you want it to do, and also complains if the file does not exist or is not a regular file:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Enter filename"
read fname

if [ ! -f "$fname" ]; then
    echo "No such file!" >&2
    exit 1
fi

lines=$( wc -l <"$fname" )
words=$( wc -w <"$fname" )
chars=$( wc -c <"$fname" )

printf 'The file "%s" has %d lines, %d words and %d characters\n' \
    "$fname" "$lines" "$words" "$chars"
```

To avoid calling `wc` three times:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Enter filename"
read fname

if [ ! -f "$fname" ]; then
    echo "No such file!" >&2
    exit 1
fi

printf 'The file "%s" has %d lines, %d words and %d characters\n' \
    "$fname" $( wc <"$fname" )
```

This uses the fact that `wc` by default outputs the number of lines, words and characters. This would be enough if you just want to have them outputted like this.

Comment: Note that some `wc` implementations include  white space around the number being returned in `wc -l < file` for instance. You can use `lines=$(($(wc -l < file)))` to strip them (that also replaces an empty output (like when the file can't be opened) with 0 (except in `dash` or `yash` where that gives you an error which you can work around with `lines=$(($(wc -l < "$file") +0))`)).

Answer (score 0):

This code is not reading the contents of the file. What you're doing in your script is getting a filename from the user and then storing it in a variable (`$file` and later `$mystring`).

When you run `for token in $mystring`, you're going through the contents of the variable `$mystring` as a list, but it only has the filename the user typed in. So all the commands referencing `$token` are manipulating the string you got from your user.

To manipulate the file contents, you could use `cat` as pointed by @faadi:
`mystring=$(cat $file)`.

EDIT:

Just correcting something on the answer. I focused on you not reading the file and failed to address another problem, brought up by @steeldriver on his comment. If you simply change the line from `mystring=$file` to `mystring=$(cat $file)` you will still not achieve what you want, because you will end up splitting the contents of the file in a list and running `wc`over those.

You could either remove the for loop, having this (if you want to store the text in a variable and use `echo`):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "File to read:"
read file
mystring=$(cat $file)
echo ""
echo "TEXT:"
echo "$mystring"
echo ""
echo -n "Lines: "
echo "$mystring" | wc -l
echo -n "Words: "
echo "$mystring" | wc -w
echo -n "Chars: "
echo "$mystring" | wc -c
```

Or, as @steeldriver suggested, just redirect the file to the STDIN of `wc` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "File to read:"
read file
echo ""
echo "TEXT:"
cat $file
echo ""
echo -n "Lines: "
wc -l < $file
echo -n "Words: "
wc -w < $file
echo -n "Chars: "
wc -c < $file
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. i haven't used the cat command much yet but it did show me what i could use it for.

Comment: I just added some more information that was missing to the answer. I'd suggest using the second code. It avoids storing the file contents in a variable, which is kind of unnecessary for the purposes of your code!